# Can double Type take parameters scala

Tags: scala

I have written the following code:

```
`  private def maxYinRange(minX: Double,
                              maxX: Double,
                              minY: Double,
                              node: PointerPSTNode): Double = {
       if (node == null || node.getY < minY) java.lang.Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
       val nodeX: Double = node.getX
       if (nodeX >= minX && nodeX <= maxX) node.getY
       val leftChild: PointerPSTNode = node.getLeftChild
       if (leftChild != null) {
       val nodeR: Double = maxX(leftChild)/*here is the error*/
       // nodeR >= points in left tree >= minX
        if (nodeR >= minX && nodeR < maxX) {
            val maxLeft: Double = maxYinRange(minX, maxX, minY, leftChild)
            val maxRight: Double =
              maxYinRange(minX, maxX, minY, node.getRightChild)
            (if (maxLeft < maxRight) maxLeft else maxRight)
          } else if (nodeR >= minX) {
            maxYinRange(minX, maxX, minY, node.getLeftChild)
          } else if (nodeR < maxX) {
            maxYinRange(minX, maxX, minY, node.getRightChild)
          }
        }
        java.lang.Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
      }`
```

but I get the following error: Double does not take parameters(the error is in this line `val nodeR: Double = maxX(leftChild)` )
and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `maxX(leftChild)` is obviously nonsense. What is it supposed to mean? What did you intend when you wrote it?

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the logic it seems like you mean

```
val nodeR: Double = leftChild.getX
```

However even if this is fixed, the function is always going to return `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` because that is the last value in the method. The rest of the code is executed but does not affect the result (the compiler will probably warn you about this)

Even when that is fixed, the logic appears unlikely to do what you want. You should also consider using `Option` to hold the leaf pointers rather than using `null`.